# OBS Studio CMAKE unable to find FFmpeg?

Tags: apt, software-installation, cmake, obs-studio

I am trying to install OBS Studio on Debian 8. I tried to follow [the official install guide](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#debian-based-build-directions) for OBS Studio, but when I try to run `cmake -DUNIX_STRUCTURE=1 DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..` I get the following error:

```
-- OBS_VERSION: 18.0.1-12-g3540e71
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find FFmpeg (missing: FFMPEG_AVCODEC_LIBRARIES
  FFMPEG_AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS avcodec avfilter avdevice avutil swscale
  avformat swresample)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindFFmpeg.cmake:151 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  deps/libff/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/obs-studio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

The only solution I could find people giving was to install `ffmpeg`; however, I have already installed `ffmpeg` from backports so this does not tell me anything. Based on the error I tried to run `apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavfilter-dev libavdevice-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libswresample-dev` and got the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec-dev : Depends: libavcodec56 (<= 6:11.8-99) but 10:2.6.9-dmo1 is to be installed or
                           libavcodec-extra-56 (<= 6:11.8-99) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libavresample-dev (= 6:11.8-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libavfilter-dev : Depends: libavresample-dev (= 6:11.8-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libavfilter5 (= 6:11.8-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libavformat-dev : Depends: libavformat56 (= 6:11.8-1~deb8u1) but 10:2.6.9-dmo1 is to be installed
 libavutil-dev : Depends: libavutil54 (= 6:11.8-1~deb8u1) but 10:2.6.9-dmo1 is to be installed
 libswresample-dev : Depends: libavutil-dev (= 7:3.2.4-1~bpo8+1) but 6:11.8-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
 libswscale-dev : Depends: libswscale3 (= 6:11.8-1~deb8u1) but 10:2.6.9-dmo1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This error persists even using the `-f` arg. The `ffmpeg` command has this output, listing all the "missing" libraries:

```
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

I have been trying to install `obs-studio` for three days now and cannot figure out a way around this. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I've run into the same issue as you. I've tried installing ffmpeg 3 different ways (from source, from repository and with ffmpeg_installer) - OBS didn't detect any of these installations.

I've downloaded a [.deb-file from the Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio/+packages) and tried installing it, but it said that I've had a bunch of old libs on my Debian 8.8.0 (I'm running stable branch).

What I did is:

1. Upgraded my whole system to the unstable (sid) branch. To do that, I needed to change my `etc/apt/sources.list` and replace the `jessie` entries with `sid`. To upgrade the whole distro, you'll have to run

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get -u dist-upgrade
   ```

   after that.
2. Installed missing `libfdk-aac1` lib. It's in the non-free branch, so you'll also need to add a `non-free` repo to your `sources.list`. Then just run:

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install libfdk-aac1
   ```
3. The last thing was `libfontconfig1` lib. Even after upgrading the whole distro to the unstable branch, the lib was still too old for OBS Studio to install. No worries, you can get a newer version from the experimental branch. Add the following line to your `sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main
   ```

   Then run:

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get -t experimental install libfontconfig1
   ```
4. Finally you can now install the deb-package from the Launchpad. I've used the one for Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus):

   ```
   dpkg -i obs-studio_18.0.1-0obsproject1~zesty_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: Ultimately, I ended up simply installing Debian Stretch and using their pre-packaged version.